# Error " The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type, " in Flutter

Tags: flutter

In my code when open this page then call **fetchData()** method in initState.fetchData methos call every 15 seconds.
**initState**

```
Timer? timer;
  Future<List<DataDoctor>>? future;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 15), (Timer t) => fetchData());
  }
```

in fetchData method geting data from API call in the API has
these data.

[![enter image description here][2]][2]
those data should retrieve to backend for now I only retrieve only **Boolean value**.
like as my code this Boolean value I get as **doctor_in** variable. if doctor_in false then should recall again API and should get data. it should at every 15 seconds until open this page.

**data retrieve code**

```
  FutureBuilder<DataDoctor> fetchData() {
    builder:
    (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        if (snapshot.data!.doctor_in == false) {
          future = client.isDoctorActive();
        }
      } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return Text('${snapshot.error}');
      }
    };
  }
```

**model**

```
class DataDoctor {
  String channelName;
  String receiver_name;
  bool doctor_in;

  DataDoctor(
      {required this.channelName,
      required this.receiver_name,
      required this.doctor_in});

  factory DataDoctor.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return DataDoctor(
      channelName: json['Mobile'] == null ? null : json['Mobile'],
      receiver_name: json['Name'] == null ? null : json['Name'],
      doctor_in: json['Boolean'] == null ? null : json['Boolean'],
    );
  }
}
```

**api call**

```
class ApiServiceDataDoctor {
  final String url =
      'https://tools.learningcontainer.com/sample-json-file.json';
  Future<List<DataDoctor>> isDoctorActive() async {
    Response response = await get(Uri.parse(url));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      Map<String, dynamic> json = jsonDecode(response.body);

      Map<String, dynamic> body = json['dataActive'];
      List<DataDoctor> datas = [DataDoctor.fromJson(body)];
      return datas;
    } else {
      throw ('cannot fetch data');
    }
  }
}
```

if doctor_in == true then **ElevatedButton** should enable

Comment: you can use `èlse`  as default return from the `fetchData`

Comment: I didn't get it

Comment: try `FutureBuilder<DataDoctor> fetchData() {
  builder:
  (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      if (snapshot.data!.doctor_in == false) {
        future = client.isDoctorActive();
      }
    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return Text('${snapshot.error}');
    } else {
      return Text("NA state");
    }
  };
}
`

Comment: show this error , The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type, 'FutureBuilder<DataDoctor>', is a potentially non-nullable type

Comment: I am not getting the `fetchData` method, is it properly included ?  maybe you are missing `return builder`, also return something inside `if` state

Comment: okay ... do know how to solve that error

Comment: I think your `fetchData` isnot properly included on question, you are following FutureBuilder, but retruning it from the method

Comment: It could be `FutureBuilder<DataDoctor> fetchData() {
  return FutureBuilder<DataDoctor>(builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      if (snapshot.data!.doctor_in == false) {
        future = client.isDoctorActive();
      }
      return DataDoctor(); // a instance
    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return Text('${snapshot.error}');
    } else {
      return Text("NA state");
    }
  });
}`

Comment: error solved bro thank you. and also do you know "snapshot.data!.doctor_in" this boolean value pass to page backend. In my code i want this boolean value to enable or disable button

Comment: The `snapshot` isn't available, I think the widget tree is needed to be changed.

Comment: yeah okay . I got it . I will try , I think I have pass  "snapshot.data!.doctor_in"  to backend from FutureBuilder<DataDoctor> fetchData() and declare to another boolean variable . Then I hope I can use in widgets. Am I correct?

Comment: What I will do, use this as a child on FutureBuilder, also My previous comment as an issue `return DataDoctor();` .

Answer (score 1):

Simply make the future nullable or provide some default value. It is throwing exception because the value can be null which will crash the application.

Answer (score 1):

```
FutureBuilder<DataDoctor> fetchData() {
    builder:
    (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {     // ⚠ This if statement is not returning anything, So you are getting error
        if (snapshot.data!.doctor_in == false) {
          future = client.isDoctorActive();
          return Text(`${snapshot.data}`);
        }
       if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return Text('${snapshot.error}');
      }
       return Text(`${snapshot.error}`) //  Add this return statement 
    };
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for you support.When I try your code at the "FutureBuilder<DataDoctor> fetchData()" show this error "The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type, 'FutureBuilder<DataDoctor>', is a potentially non-nullable type. "

Comment: Can you please clean up the code and just present the error image of the updated code and the code in the image seperately in the question and delete rest of the code. I might be able to help